# Adjusting the scroll number in responsive jcarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I'm got a responsive jcarousel working based on the example [here](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/cookbook/responsive-carousel.html).

Here's my code:

```
$(function() {
    var jcarousel = $('.jcarousel');
    //var navpanenext = '+=1';
    //var navpaneprev = '-=1';

    jcarousel
        .on('jcarousel:reload jcarousel:create', function () {
            var carousel = $(this),
                width = carousel.innerWidth();

            if (width >= 600) {
                width = width / 3;
                //navpanenext = '+=3';
                //navpaneprev = '-=3';

            } else if (width >= 350) {
                width = width / 2;
                //navpanenext = '+=2';
                //navpaneprev = '-=2';
            }

            carousel.jcarousel('items').css('width', Math.ceil(width) + 'px');
        })
        .jcarousel({
            wrap: 'circular'
        });


    $('.jcarousel-control-prev')
       .jcarouselControl({
            target: '-=3'
            //target: navpaneprev
        });

    $('.jcarousel-control-next')
        .jcarouselControl({
            target: '+=3'
            //target: navpanenext
        });
});
```

In the full width version (width > than 600) it displays 3 items at a time and if the window is resized the viewport is adjusted to show fewer items.

My controls (jacrousel-control-prev, jcarousel-control-next) scroll + or - 3 items at a time regardless of the viewport size.   is there a way to adjust the 'target' value as the viewport width is adjusted?  Inital attempts to define a variable within the reload function don't work (shown as comments as an example).

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the codes below:

```
$('.jcarousel-control-prev').click(function() {
    if (matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 630px)').matches) {
        $('.jcarousel').jcarousel('scroll', '-=3');
    }  

    else if (matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 380px) and (max-width: 630px) ').matches) {
        $('.jcarousel').jcarousel('scroll', '-=2');
    }   
});

$('.jcarousel-control-next').click(function() {
    if (matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 630px)').matches) {
        $('.jcarousel').jcarousel('scroll', '+=3');
    }  

    else if (matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 380px) and (max-width: 630px) ').matches) {
        $('.jcarousel').jcarousel('scroll', '+=2');
    }     
});
```

I determined the width (630px and 380px) using "Ctrl+Shift+M" in firefox. This might be not that appropriate but at least it works for this case.